# this delete statement doesn't execute and don't give any exception

Tags: java, postgresql

I can't explain why this delete statement doesn't execute and don't give me any exception.

here egn is a character varying in my postgresql database and i want to delete the entire row where egn = '750698'
Here is my code

```
package
com.tan;
import
java.io.File;
import
java.sql.*;
import
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import
org.w3c.dom.*;
public
class test_selectconect
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
  {
    // delte
Connection conn=
null;
Class.forName(
"org.postgresql.Driver");
try
{
conn= DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tanyaprobadatabase", "postgres", "123");
}
catch (SQLException ex1)
{
ex1.printStackTrace();
}
Statement delstmt = null;
String delQuery= "delete from tanya_students";
delQuery += "where egn= '750698'";
try
{
delstmt=conn.createStatement();
delstmt.executeUpdate(delQuery);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{}
System.out.print("delete is ok");
}
    }
```

Comment: also if the auto commit is off, the changes will not reflect in the database. Make sure auto commit is on or else give con.commit(); after the query.

Comment: you havent specified printStacktrace. So how can u say that exception does not occur

Comment: Exactly. You have no grounds for asserting no exception is thrown. Not a real question.

Comment: Thank you! now I read about printStacktrace and it didn't show any exception

Comment: You have marked an answer as correct that says you have an SQL syntax error. That error would have been reported as an exception. You therefore cannot credibly claim there was no exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need a space between table name and "where". Currently your complete query is "delete from tanya_studentswhere egn='750698'", it must be ....tanya_students where ....

Comment: thank you! that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
String delQuery= "delete from tanya_students";
delQuery += "where egn= '750698'";
```

results in "delete from tanya_studentswhere egn= '750698'"

and do not catch SQLException, just throw it, that is, add it to `throws`

Comment: why shouldn't he catch the exception?

Comment: It hides the error. If he didn't catch it the program would terminate and the error stacktrace would be printed on the console

Comment: same thing can be done in a catch

Comment: @nitgeek But it isn't being done in a catch. All that's being added by the existing catch is suppression of the exception information. He would be better off without it.